# How can I prevent iOS 5’s Wi-Fi sync from taking over my whole network connection?

Tags: wifi

My Mac, iPhone, and iPad are wirelessly connected to a Time Capsule. This works fine except when lots of data is being transferred. For example, if GBs of music are syncing from the Mac to the iPhone the Internet is almost unusable on my Mac. Safari, Mail, etc. are either very slow, or the connections time out entirely. And on the iPhone, OmniFocus syncing and Siri are incredibly slow.

Is there an easy way to prevent the iOS sync from monopolizing the 802.11n connection to leave room for other traffic?

I also saw this problem when Time Machine was backing up wirelessly to the Time Capsule. It made everything so unusable that I had to stop trying to do this. CrashPlan caused similar problems, but it has a built-in bandwidth rate-limiter, which helped.

Comment: after ur initial sync, wifi sync will only be transferring mere megabytes at a time

Comment: Yes and no. I've been thinking of changing the music on the phone and perhaps compressing it more. Plus, I think a good answer to this question would be useful in other circumstances.